# Measuring distance between two objects using CATIA VBA

Tags: vba, catia

I have a part which has two exremums on one direction. These extremums can be surface, point or line depending on part shape.

I want to measure the distance between those two extremums on the direction which they are defined by.

I couldn't find anyway to measure distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the broblem by creating a formula which is

distance(sadasd\Sketchplane,`BOUNDARY BOX\extz-2`)